# have children controllers listen for change of a parent controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I need a parent wrapper `controller` to always run and push data to any child containers. When an event on the parent wrapper changes scope of a property I need the child `controllers` to update

```
secure.controller('wrapperCtrl', function ($scope, storeFactory, safeFactory) {
    //get first store
    storeFactory.setStoreSummary(1).then(function (storeData) {
        $scope.store = storeData

        safeFactory.setSafe(storeData.safes[0].id).then(function(safeData){
            $scope.safe = safeData;
        });
    });

    $scope.changeSafe = function (safeId) {
        safeFactory.setSafe(safeId).then(function (safeData) {
            $scope.safe = safeData;
        });
    }
});
```

On the `index.html` page I have the following:

```
<div class="pageTitle">
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <h2>{{store.storeName}}</h2>
    <ul class="safes">
        <li ng-repeat="safe in store.safes"><a href="#_" ng-class="isActive(safe.id)" ng-click="changeSafe(safe.id)" ng-cloak>{{safe.name}}</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div ng-view class="fade"></div>
```

You can see the `ng-view` loads children `controllers`. Can I have something in the child controller listen for the `$scope.changeSafe` function in `wrapperCtrl` runs and re-bind it's `$scope.safe`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you need a more clear answer:

```
secure.controller('wrapperCtrl', function ($scope, storeFactory, safeFactory) {
    //get first store
    ...

    $scope.changeSafe = function (safeId) {
        safeFactory.setSafe(safeId).then(function (safeData) {
            $scope.safe = safeData;
            $scope.$broadcast('changeSafely'); // broadcast changeSafely event in parent ctrl
        });
    }
});

secure.controller('childCtrl', function($scope, ...) {

    function doSomething(){
        ...
    }

    $scope.$on('changeSafely', doSomething); // capture event and do you stuff

});
```